# Python - Creating a dictionary from external text file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

So my file looks like this:

```
0 1
0 2
0 34
0 67
1 98
1 67
1 87
2 23
2 45
2 98
...
```

and so on. My question is, how can I make a dictionary from this text file that would look like this:

```
dict = {'0':['1', '2', '34', '67']
        '1':['98', '67', '87']
        '2':['23', '45', '98']
        '3':['x','x','x']}
```

Comment: don't use `dict` as variable name, since it is a built-in type. Use `Dict` instead.

Comment: @PeterVaro Using `dict` is bad, you are right. But `Dict` isn't much better; it is intended to mean a class.

Comment: @glglgl you are right, I always use `dictionary` or `d` if I name an argument, and use a verbose name if I use it as a 'normal' variable.. Although using CapitalCaseWords for classes is nothing more, but a convention. A good one, I have to say, but not a rule!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the file is called `test.txt`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv


data = defaultdict(list)
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

then the `data` value would be:

```
{
 '0': ['1', '2', '34', '67'], 
 '1': ['98', '67', '87'], 
 '2': ['23', '45', '98'],
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A really fun, and elegant solution:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open(external_file) as f:
    map(lambda x: d[x[0]].append(x[1]), map(str.split, f))
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['98', '67', '87'], '0': ['1', '2', '34', '67'], '2': ['23', '45', '98']})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split()
        res[temp[0]].append(temp[1])
```

Comment: `line.strip().split()` is equivalent to just `line.split()` only the latter is much faster and more readable.